# Setting tenant from login page

Tags: identityserver3

In our login process with identity server we need additional input on the login page itself that will influence the tenant where user is authenticated. So we can't send this information in the acr_values that is stored in the SignInMessage cookie, but we need to somehow modify the tenant based on the user input on the login page. However, when IUserService.AuthenticateLocalAsync is called, the SignInMessage is created based on the initial values sent to /authorize endpoint.

Any tips on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control the `<form>` in the login page, then in your user service you can access the form post body (by injecting the `OwinEnvironmentService`).

Comment: Another thing, @brock-allen: if I register the userservice like `factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService, MyAuthenticationUserService>();`, how can I get the MyAuthenticationUserService instance that I need to pass when registering AuthenticationSessionValidator where I need it for duplicate logon detection?